# three different tables nested with CTE and Join SQL functions

Tags: database, join, oracle-sqldeveloper, common-table-expression

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VU4Xt.png)I have three tables that want to make some calculation based on. However, what I stated in the below did not work.
Could someone give me Any feedback?

Thank you,
formula:

(runnincost/total(gas_production of eacy year))*gas_production of each year)

as:

```
CTE  c (id,filed,year_1,year_2,year_3)

as( select g.id, g.field,

(r.year_1/sum(g.year_1))*g.year_1 ,

(r.year_2/sum(g.year_2))*g.year_2 ,

(r.year_3/sum(g.year_3))*g.year_3 ,

from group_1 as g

inner join ref_fee as r

on r.id=g.id

group  by g.field )


select c.id, c.filed,

c.year_1*b.year_1 as year_1, 

c.year_2*b.year_2 as year_2,

c.year_3*b.year_3 as year_3

from c

inner join back b

on b.id=c.id

group by c.field;
```

Answer (score 0):

"Did not work" is difficult to debug.

What is evident is that tables' aliases - in Oracle - can't have the `AS` keyword (columns can). When fixed, query looks like this:

```
WITH
   c (id,
      filed,
      year_1,
      year_2,
      year_3)
   AS
      (  SELECT g.id,
                g.field,
                (r.year_1 / SUM (g.year_1)) * g.year_1,
                (r.year_2 / SUM (g.year_2)) * g.year_2,
                (r.year_3 / SUM (g.year_3)) * g.year_3
           FROM group_1 g INNER JOIN ref_fee r ON r.id = g.id
       GROUP BY g.field)
  SELECT c.id,
         c.filed,
         c.year_1 * b.year_1 AS year_1,
         c.year_2 * b.year_2 AS year_2,
         c.year_3 * b.year_3 AS year_3
    FROM c INNER JOIN back b ON b.id = c.id
GROUP BY c.field;
```

I have no idea whether it'll work or not as I don't have your tables, nor I know what "calculations" you're about to perform.

Comment: Hi,Thank you so much for repy. did not work again.Just added the screenshot of tables and stated formula.